# App Crashes in landscape mode

Tags: android, layout, crash, landscape

App is crashing on restart of app after tablet/mobile orientation change,

I m going to develop an application in landscape mode only, and I have made a layout in layout-land with name acitivty_main and there is no any portrait layout in my application and no any layout folder as well, I have also added screenOrientation="landscape" in manifest activity.

**Activity Code Following:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml code following:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yasir.sample">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Project Structure**:

[image: Project Structure]

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
Process: com.example.yasir.sample, PID: 12611

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.yasir.sample/com.example.yasir.sample.MainActivity}: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04001b
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3151)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5205)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:219)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1741)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04001b
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2495)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:4236)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:2311)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:413)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.example.yasir.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5205) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:219) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1741) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); just remove this    since you have mentioned android:screenOrientation="landscape" in your manifest page no need of extra code in the java page

Comment: please paste error log in text form.. not image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`Resources$NotFoundException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.NotFoundException.html)

> This exception is thrown by the resource APIs when a requested
>   resource can not be found

**FYI**

- Remove
  **`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`**
- Add **`android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout"`** in Manifest section .

**`Finally`**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout">
```

Then **`Clean and Rebuild`** your project .

Comment: But its still crashing, the scenario is that i locked my tablet and changed tablet orientation to portrait than unlock tablet than app got crashed

Comment: @YasirAhmedKhan add `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout"`

Answer (score 0):

https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/dealing-with-asynctask-and-screen-orientation/

This link will explain how to prevent crashes from `AsyncTask` and `Screen Orentation`